# Why Don't DomainService Constructor Overloads Show Up as DomainContext Constructor Overloads?

Tags: silverlight, ria, domainservices

I wrote an overload for my DomainService class.  Problem is, when I recompile, it's not showing up as an overload for my DomainContext.  What's wrong?  Here is a code sample:

```
[EnableClientAccess]
public class FoodDomainService : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<FoodEntities>
{
    public FoodDomainService(CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
    }
}
```

And this doesn't work:

```
FoodDomainContext _foodContext = new FoodDomainContext(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
```

I get an error that there is no overload matching that.  Am I not allowed to do this?  Do I need an attribute of some kind?

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to do this. When newing up the context from your Silverlight client, you are not directly intantiating your service. Instead, you instantiate a proxy class that was generated by RIA Services, and that proxy class will then call your service. This is why you don't see your constructor: because RIA did not generate it in your proxy.

Doing what you're trying to do would also implicate that there is a round-trip to the server at the time of newing up that `FoodDomainContext` class, which is not going to happen, because you need to complete the initialisation of that object before you can do so.

Anyway, instead of that you can create a method called SetCurrentCulture() and then call it **after** initializing the proxy.

Comment: The two suggestions I've been given are essentially the same.  Yet, they both don't work.  I've made a public method in my DomainService class that is not accessible, for some reason, in my DomainContext class.  I don't see any attributes on the methods that are viewable (query methods, for example) at all.  So what am I missing?  Am I putting this method in the wrong place?  I'm putting it in the XXXDomainService class, as a public method, with no attributes.

Comment: Your method has to take entities as input/output to be automatically visible. Try adding the `[Invoke]` attribute and maybe pass the culture as a `string` that you can then parse with `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture` (although I think it _should_ work by passing a `CultureInfo`)

Answer (score 0):

This will not work because DomainContext is generated on client code of silverlight, click on view all folders or jump to definition and you will see that code generated will not contain your extra constructor.

Instead you will have to create a method in your domain service and pass information to server.

```
public SetCultreInfo(int lang,...)
{
   ..  set culture info
}
```

On your client, inside constructor you should call,

```
public MyDomainContext()
{
    this.SetCulture(....);
}
```